# Laravel query distinct values from Foreign table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a laravel project with posts table and make table. I have established a relationship between make and post tables.
Posts table contain make_id. 
I want to query and get all the unique makes from all posts. I did a query and got unique make_id's.But unable to get unique make_names. What am I missing here?

**PostModel:**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Post;
use App\Make;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected $dates = ['status_change'];


    public function make_rel()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Make::class, 'make_id' ,'id','make_logo');
    }

}
```

**My Query:**

```
    $makesforsearch = Post::select('make_id')->distinct()->pluck('make_id');
```

**Result I get**

```
Collection {#511 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => "9"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "5"
    3 => "6"
    4 => "11"
  ]
}
```

This result is correct. But instead of 9,1,5,6, and 11. I should get their make names which are BMW, Harley, Roayl, Indian and Honda. Here's a screenshot of make table below.

[image]

What am I missing? How to fix it?

Comment: You should do a query using `Make` class and check if it has relative Posts existing and then pluck names. Or you can send 2 queries.

Comment: You  want distinct make names, It doesn't have anything to do with post, does it?

Comment: I want distict make names that has a post. There are over 100 makes. But only 10 used at various posts. I need names of these 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something from `Make`. So start from `Make`.
And to filter only makes which has post, use `whereHas()`

```php
$uniqueMakeNames = Make::whereHas('posts')->pluck('make_name')->unique();
```

Make sure that you have defined `postst()` relationship on `Make` model.

```php
class Make extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you did use `::select('make_id')` and then `->pluck('make_id')`.
Why are you surprised your results only contain what you've plucked?

Try `Posts::all()->get()->make_rel()->distinct()` or the same code but with `make_rel` and not `make_rel()`

Comment: @Thaha You don't have to get unique make_ids at all, you can get unique model instances of Make instead and then get names from them.
This is why you've set up `make_rel` relation.

Comment: I tried it, doesn't work.
@TharakaDilshan what is correct then?